# Select splat in a subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql

Obviously, `'select *'` is never a good idea.

HOWEVER, I have taken a job with an org that allowed this cancer to spread.

They have huge queries, using `select *` as SUB-QUERIES, when the coder only needed 3 or 4 columns.

```
 select t.field1, t.field2, t.field3, x.field4 ...
   from table t
   left join (select * from table where .... ) x
     on x.field5 = t.field5 
   left join (select * from table where .... ) y
     on y.field6 = t.field6
   left join (select * from table where .... ) z
     on z.field7 = t.field7
```

Performance on this beast is a dog.

The databases we pull from we don't own, so I don't have rights to get an estimated or actual execution plan.

Before I start rewriting these queries, is the query optimizer on the M$ SQL Server smart enough to translate the splat into just the needed columns?  Or do I start targeting one query a day at lunch?

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Perhaps https://dba.stackexchange.com is more suited for your question. Unless you can provide us with the required context.

Comment: Harsh dude.  Harsh.

Comment: Well, I did spare you a bit. I didn't downvote :)

Comment: Hmmm...DBAs I know don't write code.  Not sure what they do....  Probably nothing.

Comment: Harsh dude. Harsh.

Comment: Yes.  the optimizer is smart enough to only gather the columns needed for the result set, as well as skipping left joins that are not needed for the result set.  More than likely, your performance problem is in the Where clause.